# Parse css color channels via PHP

Tags: php, css

How can i get separate channels from color string like: "#1122f0" via PHP to get this:

```
$color = substr("#1122f0", 1); // get "1122f0"
// wanted:
$red = 0x11;
$green = 0x22;
$blue = 0xf0;
```

Comment: I'd suggest start by using substring(), or str_split()

Comment: Perhaps take every 2 characters via substring and just append the '#' to the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list($red, $green, $blue) = array_map('dechex',
  sscanf('#1122f0', '#%02x%02x%02x'));
```

You can also parse the components as strings:

```
list($red, $green, $blue) = sscanf('#1122f0', '#%02s%02s%02s');
```

But the first solution would also (sort of) validate your color string :)